# Tag description etc not easily accessible from mobile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, user-interface, mobile-web

On my iPhone, I don't have the "hover" action, so I cannot hover over a tag to see its description.

Clicking on a tag takes me to a screen with questions for that tag, which is vaguely helpful as well, but sometimes doesn't reveal too much about the tag (especially for the fuzzy tags you are probably wondering about in the first place).

I would like to be able to access the tag wiki etc from the mobile interface.

For example, for [mobile-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-web), the desktop version already features a tag wiki excerpt near the top of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-web but it's not there in the mobile view. What it does show in the mobile view is ... the tag itself as a link to the page you are currently viewing (sic). Could that be changed to link to the tag description instead, or is that too obscure?

> [image: Partial screen shot]

If it cannot be directly accommodated, how about adding a link to the top -- or, heck, the bottom -- of the mobile page? https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mobile-web/info is what the desktop version links to in the "Learn more..." link near the top of the page, below the wiki excerpt.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to longpress on the tag, and show the hover state?

Comment: A long press opens up Safari's context menu, and the browser I vastly prefer over Safari behaves similarly.

Comment: Chrome? Yes, you should be able to long press and then press cancel, and show it. At least that's how it works on Android...

Comment: We're not on android here…

Comment: Cancel simply cancels (and no Chrome here,either).

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Android, and can confirm that a long press shows a browser context menu, and cancelling it doesn't magically reveal a hover state. Definite +1 for this feature request.

Comment: Incidentally, the Stack Exchange Android app doesn't seem to have access to tag descriptions/wikis, either - or at least not in any obvious way.

Comment: See also now the tangentially related follow-up request http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292361/make-full-tag-wiki-accessible-from-mobile-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag excerpt is now displayed on top of the page in mobile web version. SE team has implemented this as a part of **[Mobile web refresher, part 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239378/mobile-web-refresher-part-3).**

Screenshot from iPhone:

[image]