# Make full tag wiki accessible from mobile view

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, mobile-web

When you visit the site using a mobile browser<sup>1</sup>, the tag view shows you the questions for a particular tag, but there is no way to directly access the tag wiki, with more documentation for this particular tag.

For example, here is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby:

> [image: Stolen image from old question]

My suggestion would be to make the [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) tag link above the brief description of the tag (aka tag wiki excerpt) take you to the (non-excerpt) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info) rather than back to the page you are already looking at.

I posted a [related request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258775/tag-description-etc-not-easily-accessible-from-mobile) earlier<sup>2</sup> and it was quickly accommodated.  I'm hoping this suggested modification will be similarly easy to accept.

---

<sup>1</sup> ... or in a desktop browser, by clicking the "mobile" link in the page footer; click "full site" to return to the desktop skin.

<sup>2</sup> ... and stole the image above from the [helpful answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271439/874188).